# Ecto raw sql with single result in a quick way

Tags: elixir, ecto

As an example I'm using the following right now.

```rb
query = """
  SELECT reltuples
  AS approximate_row_count
  FROM pg_class
  WHERE relname = 'table';
"""

query
|> Repo.query!()
|> Map.get(:rows)
|> List.flatten()
|> List.first()
|> trunc()
```

It executes the query, receives the result

```rb
%Postgrex.Result{
  columns: ["approximate_row_count"],
  command: :select,
  connection_id: 17152,
  messages: [],
  num_rows: 1,
  rows: [[1494644.0]]
}
```

selects the rows `[[1494644.0]]`

flattens the list `[1494644.0]`

gets the first entry `1494644.0`

and converts it to an integer `1494644`

I feel like apart form the last step, there has to be a shorter way for this. But I have not found it yet. Please note, that I'm not looking for a way to execute that simple query as an ecto query, but rather as raw sql. Because I use a lot more complicated queries with the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with pattern matching.

```rb
with [[result]] <- Repo.query!(query).rows,
  do: trunc(result)
```

This would return all the rows from the result back if there is more than one row returned. To fully mimic the original behavior (`List.first/1` which is essentially the same as [`hd/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#hd/1)), use:

```rb
with [[result|_]|_] <- Repo.query!(query).rows,
  do: trunc(result)
```

Also, one might gracefully handle errors with `else:` clause.

Comment: Somehow pattern matching keeps to be the answer in Elixir.  Awesome, thanks!